# Why does my Qualtrics JS in header only seem to work for the first page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, qualtrics

I have tried to place it in in the Qualtrics header with the  tag and the JS section within the individual questions in Qualtrics.

This code is successful in hiding the "Powered by Qualtrics" tab at the bottom of the first question, but every other question after the first one will show the "Powered by Qualtrics" tab.

FYI this Qualtrics survey is currently embedded on another site via iframe tags.

Any thoughts?

```
<script>
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() 
{ 
    var plug = document.getElementById("Plug");
    plug.style.cssText += ';display:none !important;';
}); 
</script>
```

Source: [KamikazeBot/The Qualtrics HTML_CSS Bible](https://gist.github.com/KamikazeBot/7d18eb3bea73b972047d)

Comment: This sounds to be an issue with the new jfe engine. When you are previewing the survey does it appear with the mobile preview sidebar?

Comment: Same thing occurs in the survey preview. It gets blocked in the first question, but every question after that, it is still showing up.

Does it have to do with: Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() not re-executing when each question loads?

Comment: That seems likely. Ill take a look monday and see if i can sort something out

Comment: Thank you, @AnthonyTJRivas !

Comment: Any chance of a link to the particular study? I attempted  direct copy of the code on my account and it worked successfully

Comment: I haven't posted the survey, just trying to see if I could make it work with a template study. Did you just paste the code into the header section within Qualtrics or to each question?

Comment: Just within the header

Comment: Hmm, weird. I can still only get it to hide only on first question. Shucks :(

Comment: If its possible to get a link. Even a Preview mode link.Id be happy to give it a look and see what i can sort out.

Comment: here's a [link](https://s.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_5aT48YcoQhayBhP) to the preview mode. thanks!

Comment: This appears to actually be caused by the new transition effects. Not sure at the moment how to solve it(though I am sure there is a solution and will continue working on this) a temporary solution is to use no transition effects.

Comment: Interesting. I got it to work if I disable the transition effects. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the Footer under Look & Feel -> Advanced:

```
<script>

    var plug = document.getElementById('Plug');

    if (plug) {
        plug.parentNode.removeChild(plug);
    } 

</script>
```